# How to plot and save with an <AxesSubplot:> output

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandapower

I am using this [function](https://github.com/e2nIEE/pandapower/blob/develop/pandapower/plotting/simple_plot.py)

It return one AxesSubplot:

I would like to save the plot that is ploted when `show_plot=True` as a png without changing the function.

How should I proceed ?

Best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the whole figure, you could try:

```
ax.get_figure().savefig('fig_name.png')
```

If you have a figure with multiple subplots and you want to only extract one (`ax`):

```
# Get the bounding box of the subplot and expand it to include the axis labels and ticks.
# You will have to play with the expanded parameters.
subplot_box = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(ax.get_figure().dpi_scale_trans.inverted()).expanded(1.2, 1.4)
ax.get_figure().savefig('subplot.png', bbox_inches=extent)
```

Comment: @ThomasLESIEUR no problem. I edited the answer to add how to do it in case you will need the same for only a subplot of a larger figure.

Comment: Bbox_inches=‘tight’ should do the same thing without playing with “expanded parameters”.

Comment: @JodyKlymak to extract a subplot only? I tried but it doesn't work, it sets the box to the whole figure automatically

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood that there was more than one axes.  I guess if you want just one axes out of many, then ax.get_tightbbox() should work in your code above.

Comment: @JodyKlymak that's a good one yeah. I tried by passing `ax.get_figure().canvas.get_renderer()` as renderer but it saves a blank figure for some reason

Comment: you may have to trigger a draw before the bbox will be correct?  You can print the bbox to check if it makes sense.